# The Orthogonal Projection Matrix Sizes not working out

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, orthogonality

I need to find the orthogonal projection matrix given the system of linear equations:

$
x_1 + x_2 - x_3 = 0 \\
x_1 - x_2 + 3x_3 = 0 \\
$

Which gives the following matrix:

$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 1 & -1 & 0\\
        1 & -1 & 3 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

With reduced row echelon form:

$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
        0 & 1 & -2 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Making the solutions

$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        x_1 \\
        x_2 \\
        x_3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
= x_3
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

So in order to find the orthogonal projection matrix, I use the following equation.

$P_W = C(C^TC)^{-1}C^T$

Where $C$ equals the basis which is
$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        -1 \\
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$
correct?

So plugging in C into the equation $P_W$ and solving, I get

$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1/3 & 2/3 & 1/3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

But the book says the answer is

$
P_W = 1/6
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -2 & -1\\
        -2 & 4 & 2\\
        -1 & 2 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

I don't know how they got that. I'm not getting the same answer. Is my basis wrong to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

$C^TC$ is just a scalar, so you’re effectively multiplying a $3\times1$ matrix by a $1\times3$ matrix. The result should be a $3\times3$ in which the elements are all of the possible products of pairs of elements of $C$. It looks like you might have ended up simply squaring each component of $C$ of instead.